# iOS - core data - table view scroll to newly added record

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Overview:**

I have an iOS project in with the following:

- core data (using `NSFetchedResultsController`)
- displaying the data in a table view (`UITableView`)

**What I want to do:**

- When a user adds a record, I want to scroll to the newly added record.

**What I have done**

1. When a new record is added, Inside the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method, I store the index path in a property `lastAddedIndexPath` when the type is insert / update / move
2. After invoking save, I scroll to the "lastAddedIndexPath"

**Code (NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)**

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{       
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"going to store insert - scroll");
                self.lastAddedIndexPath = newIndexPath;
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"going to store update - scroll");
                self.lastAddedIndexPath = newIndexPath;
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"going to store move - scroll");
                self.lastAddedIndexPath = newIndexPath;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code to scroll**

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (self.beganUpdates) //already [self.tableView beginUpdates] invoked
    {
        [self scrollToLastAddedIndexPath];  //contains the logic to scroll
        [self.tableView endUpdates];   
    }
}
```

**Problem**

- I think the record is added to the table view asynchronously in a different thread.
- so even after saving the database, when I scroll to the `lastAddedIndexPath` the record in the table doesn't exist yet.

**Questions**

1. How would I be able to scroll to the newly added record path after the record has been added to the table view ?
2. Should I use notifications to know when the database is saved ?
3. Is there any other alternate approach ?

Comment: Where is your [self.tableView endUpdates] call? You want the scroll to happen just after that.

Comment: I am performing scrolling inside controllerDidChangeContent: I have reedited question to show the code.

Comment: So what happens if you switch the scroll and the end updates around?

Comment: awesome !!!!!!! saved my day thank you so much, I was breaking my head all day. And the problem was that when the a new record was added to the end of the table view, the indexPath.row was greater than [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] and caused a crash

Comment: I'll post that as an answer, then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scrolling has to happen after `[self.tableView endUpdates]` since the new row is not added to the table until that point. So switch the two statements around:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
{ 
    if (self.beganUpdates) //already [self.tableView beginUpdates] invoked 
    { 
        [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
        [self scrollToLastAddedIndexPath];  //contains the logic to scroll 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the scrolling in:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
```

Alternatively you could use KVO to be notified when a new record is added.

Comment: thanks, I am performing scrolling inside controllerDidChangeContent: but dosen't seem to work. have reedited question to show the code. Let me try KVO.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario i need show a last added object on top of the table view so i used a different approach,  i used NSSortDescriptor to sort the array and then reload the table view every time it add/delete any record. like this

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]autorelease];
NSArray * sortDescriptorArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil]autorelease];

self.commitsList =  [[self.listItem.itemCommit allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];

[tblView reloadData];
```

And then you can use any key related to your data in `initWithKey` and sort your array to resolve this.
And in `CellForRowIndex` method of table view you can use this array to populate tableview.

Comment: thanks Shahid, but in my case, I am sorting it based on a different field and i can't change the sorting order, so i want to just scroll to that record

Comment: You can use this method scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Comment: and sort before that what you usually do. it will point the row you added recently